# Why not view updating?

Tags: javascript, redux

console.log function in HelloWorld function is showing updated state so why is paragraph in render function not updating? I can't seem to be able to fix render not updating.
Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
var initialState = {value: 0};
function counterReducer(state=initialState,action) {
    if(action.type === 'counter/increment') {
        return { 
            ...state,
            value: state.value + 1
        }
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}
const store = configureStore({reducer: counterReducer});
store.dispatch({type: 'counter/increment'});
class Counter extends React.Component {
    HelloWorld = () => {
        store.dispatch({type: 'counter/increment'});
        console.log(store.getState().value);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <p>{store.getState().value}</p>
            <button onClick={this.HelloWorld}>Add</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to use 'React-Redux' with @ReduxJS/toolkit to get render() function to update webpage. To get ReduxJS/toolkit to update webpage without 'React-Redux'? Answer: You use store.subscribe() function instead, for eg)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
var initialState = {value: 0};
function counterReducer(state=initialState,action) {
    if(action.type === 'counter/increment') {
        return { 
            ...state,
            value: state.value + 1
        }
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}
const store = configureStore({reducer: counterReducer});
class Counter extends React.Component {
    HelloWorld = () => {
        store.dispatch({type: 'counter/increment'});
        console.log(store.getState().value);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <p id="update"></p>
            <button onClick={this.HelloWorld}>Add</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
function Two() {
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = store.getState().value;
}
store.subscribe(Two);
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

More information [Why](https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do ReduxJS/toolkit with React-Redux:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {Provider,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
var initialState = {value: 0};
function counterReducer(state=initialState,action) {
    if(action.type === 'counter/increment') {
        return {
            ...state,
            value: state.value+1
        };
    }
    return state;
}
const store = configureStore({reducer: counterReducer});
function Counter() {
    function HelloWorld() {
        store.dispatch({type: 'counter/increment'});
    }
    let x = useSelector((state) => state.value);
    return (
        <div>
        <p>{x}</p>
        <button onClick={HelloWorld}>Add</button>
        </div>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Counter />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do answer the mapStateToProps (old fashioned way)?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {Provider,connect} from 'react-redux';
var initialState = {value: 0};
function counterReducer(state=initialState,action) {
    if(action.type === 'counter/increment') {
        return {
            ...state,
            value: state.value+1
        };
    }
    return state;
}
const store = configureStore({reducer: counterReducer});
function Counter(props) {
    function HelloWorld() {
        store.dispatch({type: 'counter/increment'});
    }
    return (
        <div>
        <p>{props.x}</p>
        <button onClick={HelloWorld}>Add</button>
        </div>
    );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    x: state.value
})
Counter = connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Counter />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How to do mapDispatchToProps?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {Provider,connect} from 'react-redux';
var initialState = {value: 0};
function counterReducer(state=initialState,action) {
    if(action.type === 'counter/increment') {
        return {
            ...state,
            value: state.value+1
        };
    }
    return state;
}
const store = configureStore({reducer: counterReducer});
function Counter(props) {
    return (
        <div>
        <p>{props.x}</p>
        <button onClick={props.HelloWorld}>Add</button>
        </div>
    );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    x: state.value
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    HelloWorld: () => {dispatch({type: 'counter/increment'})}
})
Counter = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Counter />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```